# ORDER BY that doesn't contain repeating values

Tags: postgresql, select, order-by

[Relevant SQL Fiddle (postgres 9.2)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/35bf0/2/0)

How do I state a SELECT .. ORDER BY .. that avoids having repeated values for a column?

That is, for rows of the column "rank" (1,3,3,1) how do I get a result so that rows of that column are ordered as (1,3,1,3), garuanteeing that a row with column value 1 is never follow by a row with column value 1, and similar for other rows values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot avoid in it in all cases (if more than 50% of the rows have the same value in the column.) One way to achieve a "shuffle" result, similar to what you want is by using window function:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colX) AS rn
    FROM tableX 
  )
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY rn, colX ;
```

The above will not avoid all cases though. If for example, the values in the column are `1,1,1,1,2,2,3`, you'll get:

```
1,2,3,1,2,1,1
```

and not the (better):

```
1,2,1,3,1,2,1
```